# Automatically adding text to URLs / Redirecting on sites you dont own

Tags: url, youtube, greasemonkey, userscripts

I want to make it so that every time I go to [this site](http://www.youtube.com/user/example/videos) it automatically redirects [here](http://www.youtube.com/user/example/videos?shelf_id=1&sort=dd&view=0)

Is it possible to do this with the greasemonkey add-on for firefox?
Is it even feasable outside of greasemonkey?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do this with for example this chrome extension:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/switcheroo-redirector/cnmciclhnghalnpfhhleggldniplelbg